# How to check if SSIS generated output file within JAMS workflow

Tags: ssis, workflow

I have a JAMS workflow within which I am calling the SSIS package. How to know if SSIS generated an output file using variables? I can check the files by accessing the file location. But need to check it just by variable, instead of setting up an FTP session and checking the files existance.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on a JAMS forum. This is not a SSIS question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.